# Optaplanner CVRP - capacity feasible (overconstrained optimization)

Tags: java, optaplanner

i'm new to OptaPlanner so this question can be trivial.
Playing with CVRP example i've added some customer that overload the vehicle capacity obviously the problem is become not feasible. 
the result that i aim to achieve is obtain the route that involve only a subset of customer in order to not overload the vehicle's capacity and so not broke the hard constraint.

i have think to use:

- a nullable variable, but it can't be used with chained graph.
- with factchange, remove entity  that overload the capacity, but i think that using such workaround i can't obtain the best fit load capacity.

any suggestion is really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 1 "dummy vehicle" and threat it differently in your score rules: ignore all constraints if Vehicle.isDummy() is true, including distances costs and capacity costs. Then add add an extra soft constraint for customers that are services by the dummy vehicle (= not being serviced), depending on your business.